# Codeigniter update mysql data using increment

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to add 1 to my column named **`SIZE`** (integer), this is my query:

```
$this->dbsections->update('sections', "SIZE = SIZE + 1");
```

But in the error message, it reads as:

```
UPDATE `sections` SET `SIZE = SIZE +` 1 = '' WHERE `NAME` = 'ABC'
```

Comment: I can't remember off hand, can you do `$this->dbsections->update('sections', ['size' => 'size + 1']);`  I have a feeling this won't work and you might need to write the query in a different way, as a full query

Comment: Yes, it didn't worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your update query

```
$this->dbsections->set('SIZE', 'SIZE+1', FALSE);// third parameter FALSE
$this->dbsections->where('NAME', "ABC");
$this->dbsections->update('sections');
```

> set() will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that
>   will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$this->dbsections->query("UPDATE sections SET SIZE = SIZE + 1 WHERE NAME = 'ABC'");
```

Comment: NAME is a MySQL reserved word so might need escaping.  Whilst this does answer the specific question asked, if other fields needed updating also, the query string itself could get quite large and unreadable if not formatted neatly; as a result there are better ways of doing this

Comment: @gabe3886 NAME is keyword in mysql not reserved check there is no __(R)__ after name!! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Saty My mistake, I misread the documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It's probably still worth escaping the column names though, just in case that changes in a future version.